# New numpy overflow encountered in code that worked fine 6 weeks ago

Tags: python, numpy

I use a molecular descriptor calculator called mordred-descriptor periodically. The last time I ran it (Jan 11 2021) it worked fine (job completed with no errors).

The error reference is numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:1897: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
return um.multiply.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)

This started for me on Feb 22 2021, on 3 different machines (2 Win 10 64-bit, and OSX 10.14).

On all machines the code is run in environments created and accessed through Anaconda3 (with conda). Anaconda navigator versions 1.9.2, 1.9.12 and 1.10. I have multiple environments on each machine, with mordred available from at least 2 environments on each, in python 3.7.

All machines now exhibit the problem, whether or not an environment has been updated or not (to my knowledge). I have found no way to restore the previously error-free execution. This issue was reported by a user in Nov 2019 on the Issues page on the mordred github site. A second report of the problem was made to the page Feb 11 2021. There have been no replies with resolution on the github page.

I have downgraded numpy as far as possible in python 3.7, and same for pandas. And created new environments from scratch.

Over the few years I've used mordred, a few bugs have needed to be fixed, but those episodes turned out well (e.g. replacing ix with iloc (or iat) in a few lines of code when ix was deprecated in pandas).

By no means am I a python expert, but I have learned a bit using mordred. This one has me stumped.

Conda is configured with autoupdate on for 2 machines and off for 1, but makes no difference for this problem.

I'm not sure where else I should be looking, so I'm hoping someone who knows better than me will help.

Thanks,

plkx

Comment: This seems to be data dependent.  What changes in the data from one run to another ?

Comment: Nothing, that I can tell. I have used the same exact same input file on all machines. I have also created input files that confirm that the problems occurs (at least some of the time) with molecules above a certain size (number of carbon atoms, all matrices are square n×n where n = number of carbon atoms). A variety of matrices are derived and eigenvalues calculated from them to get descriptors.

Comment: To add context - I've calculated descriptors for molecules with > 120 carbon atoms successfully. The problem occurs now for molecules with more than ~18 non-hydrogen atoms. Also, the main input file I've been using for tests is the exact file that ran perfectly 6 weeks ago.

Comment: It does fail on an overflow multiplying all values in a matrix with each other so the data is certainly at the root of this issue. I know nothing about mordred but if you have some packages in there that implement large number calculations that could be a factor (if a different version or bit size differ between machines)

Comment: If you're getting an overflow error when dimensionality gets above a certain size, and the error is specifically in a `multiply.reduce` step (i.e. multiply everything in a dimension) -  there's not much we can do without any code.  It's probably just too many numbers being multiplied for your system to handle.

Comment: or rather, the product is bigger than your system can handle

Comment: I'm narrowing down the culprit code (I think). Based on the descriptors that are not reported. Of the 1826 descriptors calculated, I've identified 213 that are failing under the recent circumstances. Since some may fail because they use a value that fails calculation, they are not the source of the overflow error. I'm going through each module.